# Encapsulating sub-namespaces in typescript

Tags: module, typescript, encapsulation

The project I'm working on, being rather large, consists of one master module, which I'd like to be the API interface, with a number of sub-modules defined within it. This is being done as follows:

```
<Library.ts>
module Library { }

<Core/Core.ts>
module Library.Core {}
```

Often the submodules will span a number of files. The problem I'm having is in such situations, one file cannot use non-exported properties defined within the same sub-module, but in another file.

Is there any way I can use these properties, or failing that, any way I can prevent the entirety of a sub-module's exports being exposed within its parent module?

Comment: [This](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/407063) is the VERY long discussion on CodePlex that I believe is relevant to what you are looking for. It talks about the goals some folks have and the technical issues that arise when considering that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript and the very nature of how a `module` is built.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can use these properties, or failing that, any way I can prevent the entirety of a sub-module's exports being exposed within its parent module?

No. You need to export from `module Foo` for it to be available to `module Foo` in another file. The same applies to submodules